# Standard deviation of each row between two columns in R

Tags: arrays, r, standards, deviation

I have a simple query. I am trying to get the standard deviation of each row between two columns in an array (n=2 for the length of the array; I know it's a small sample size)

It forms part of a longer code but simply:

```
data$i  <- sd(data$x, data$y)^2 + (0.1)^2 / data$j
```

so my data would look like this:

```
x   y
3   13
4   9
19  3
14  3
18  4
3   10
9   4
3   6
3   8
10  9
8   10
11  9
13  12
15  14
19  16
8   8
8   18
11  14
10  12
18  14
12  20
6   8
```

and, just using the `sd()`, I would like to get this:

```
7.1
3.5
11.3
7.8
9.9
4.9
3.5
2.1
3.5
0.7
1.4
1.4
0.7
0.7
2.1
0.0
7.1
2.1
1.4
2.8
5.7
1.4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To apply `sd()` across the rows, you would use `apply`

```
apply(data[, c("x","y")],1,sd)
```